# How to say "offer" (as in "job offer") in Chinese?

Tags: translation, word-requests

Such as "offer" in:

> 我有了CUHK的入学许可 = I got an *offer* from CUHK.
>
> 还没有一个地方要我 = I still don't have any *offers*.

I think there is no such noun in Chinese. Is there?

Answer (score 5):

I looked for [example sentences using "offer" on Tatoeba.org](http://tatoeba.org/eng/sentences/search?query=offer&from=eng&to=cmn), and most of them use 提议 as [Bojin Li mentioned](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/1453/16).

> It was foolish of you to accept his offer.
>
> [你真笨去接受他的提議。](http://tatoeba.org/eng/sentences/show/760729)

However, one did specifically relate to a job offer and used 工作錄取.

> The job offer still stands.
>
> [這份工作錄取仍然有效。](http://tatoeba.org/eng/sentences/show/793944)

Another one used 工作机会, but that seems closer to "job opportunity" than "job offer".

> I received a good job offer.
>
> 我得到了一个好的工作机会。

I found 16 total sentences that used "offer" as a noun. They translated it using the following terms:

- 提议 - 7 sentences
- 报价 - 4 sentences used this, but it's specifically related to making an offer in a business transaction when negotiating a price.
- 工作錄取 - 1 sentence.
- 工作机会 - 1 sentence, but it seems closer to opportunity than offer.
- 请求 - 1 sentence translated offer of support as 支援请求
- 资助 - 1 sentence used this, but again it's specifically a financial offer of help.
- 建议 - 1 sentence, but it seems closer to suggestion than offer.

Comment: It's even worse as a verb, I think. 'He offered to carry my bags' and many other examples like it are hard to translate into Chinese.

Answer (score 4):

You can use 录取通知书, but it is pretty formal. Often it is used for an admission notice of a school, but it can also mean job offer. So you can use 工作录取通知书, but it is not that often used.

You can also use 工作邀请. An example: 他只得到了一份工作邀请 means "He has only had one job offer".

On [Nciku](http://www.nciku.com/search/all/%E5%B7%A5%E4%BD%9C%E9%82%80%E8%AF%B7) I also found this example:

> 他顺利通过五场面试，并且每次面试后都收到了一份工作邀请。
>
> He sailed through five interviews and was offered a job after each interview.

Answer (score 2):

When in translation English to Chinese.
We tend to use more verb than noun.

> 我被CUHK录取了 = "I got an offer from CUHK."
>
> 还没有一个地方要我
> 我还没有工作 = "I still don't have any offers."

If you have to find the relative noun try 入取通知书 in acceptance from study and 工作邀请函 in acceptance from work.

Answer (score 1):

As is the way of most languages, the meaning of a term often varies depending on the context.  The word [offer](http://www.iciba.com/offer), when used as a verb, commonly means to provide(提供), furnish/offer(供奉), or propose(提议).  However in the context of your example, `offer` is being used as a noun, and its meaning is more akin to the notion of `act of expressing willingness`(表示愿意). Specifically, CUHK, by extending you an offer(of admission), has agreed to your previous application of requesting to be a student there.  Similarly, by not having any offers, not a single entity has agreed to whatever proposition you proposed.  As for a concise Chinese translation, I can't think of one at the moment that accurately captures the meaning you are trying to convey.  The closest one would probably be 提议, but it is not quite right.

Comment: Thank you but I think "提议" is quite different from "工作邀请" and "入学许可" No such word in Chinese:(

Answer (score 0):

You are right that there is no Chinese words for offer, mainly because if the people can accept Western systems, they would just quote the english word, e.g. in HK. If they are reluctant to accept the Western system, they just don't have a concept of "offer", hence not a word for it.